# How to one-hot encode category features with pandas or tensorflow?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

The data is like this:

```
   features1    features2       labels
1      1            563           1
2      1            254           1
3   missing         145           1
4      0            126           1
5      0            145           0
6      1            124           0
7      0            456           0
```

I am going to apply this data to a Tensorflow training process, so I wanna one-hot encode the feature1's values.

the matrix of the data above is :

```
[[1,563,1],
 [2,254,1],
 [missing,145,1],
 [0,126,1],
 [0,145,0],
 [1,124,0],
 [0,456,0]]
```

So I think it can be one-hot encoded to this:

```
> [1,0,0] represents 1 
> [0,1,0] represents 0
> [0,0,1] represents 'missing'
```

and the output I want is like:

```
[[1,0,0,563,1],
 [1,0,0,254,1],
 [0,0,1,145,1],
 [0,1,0,126,1],
 [0,1,0,145,0],
 [1,0,0,124,0],
 [0,1,0,456,0]]
```

I've tried pd.get_dummies.But I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how did you use pd.get_dummies but please note that this function generates a new data frame or array for you , so if you want to apply 1 hot encoding to 1st column in your array and keep the other columns as is ,  you need to reassign the your array like so :

```
newArrayWithOneHotEncoding = pd.get_dummies(arrayThatYouWantToTransform, columns = ['firstColumnHeader'])
```

**Update :**
I forgot to mention that you need to set a distinct value for the missing for example -1 , then apply the one Hot Encoding this way you will have three new columns

Comment: That means it will create new variables into the new array, right?

Comment: YES it will , it will also remove the original variable that you did the one hot encoding for

Comment: Thank you .this will create too many new variables if there are many categories. Any way can assign the one_hot encoded  array into the original variable?